Gap in corner of roofing trim (fascia?)
https://imgur.com/a/d9GZpQ1
I noticed the mentioned gap in the corner of the trim along the roof-line of my home. Looks like due to moisture, maybe, the two boards have separated, as you can see the nails have pulled through.
Am I able to seal this up with some sort of sealant? Seems a little too large. Is there some sort of plate I can put up and then seal?

Looks to me like the boards have shrunk.  Personally, I'd just get a piece of aluminum (or maybe vinyl) flashing and wrap it around the corner.  Paint to match.  If you can, slip the top up behind the back of the gutter.
